# No response from Scanner when trying to print a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written the following method to test out using the Scanner class within my larger class. I run a debug and get no stack, or any kind of response on my console.

```
public static void scan(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{ 
    File text = new File("/Users/CodeBoy/Desktop/test.txt ");

    int lineNumber = 1;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("line " + lineNumber + " :" + str);  
        lineNumber++;
    }
        scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: There is an extra space in your `text`. Try `"/Users/CodeBoy/Desktop/test.txt"`

Comment: Do you have any text in the file?

Comment: Two lines, they say "This is a test string
This is a new line
"

Comment: Your method says `scan`, maybe you were looking for `main`? Is this method even executing? Where do you call this method?

Comment: I commented out the section where I invoked it and didn't notice T_T               Thanks....